# Arabic rendering on mobile has different result between web and mobile

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, mobile

I have same text and use same specified font but in web and mobile has different result
this is the result is, btw i tested in native, react-native and flutter still get same result even in real device or emulator

web:

[image]

mobile:

[image]

thanks in advance

[udpated]

is use RichText widget in flutter that solve my problem, but i don't know how in react native and android native (kotlin, compose) use what

Comment: According to your images, the text seems to be looking exactly same but there might be fontSize issue which you can easily change.

Comment: no i have add more font size still same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[udpated]

i use RichText widget in flutter that solve my problem, but i don't know how in react native and android native (kotlin, compose) use what